# find hash value from key in template toolkit

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

have simple hash, which is being used to pupulate a select option. I want to order it on values, but I am not able to print the keys...

```
[%- FOREACH val IN myList.values.sort -%]<option value="[%- myList.$val.key -%]">[%- val -%]</option>[% END %]
```

the KEY is coming null..... i tried many things, it is not working.

so that select option is coming as:

```
<option value="">roger1</option>
```

all keys and values are unique.

how can i get the key if i know the value, from a hash?

Comment: Hashes are designed to quickly extract the value given the key, but to go the other way around you would have to iterate through all the key-value pairs of the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pairs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/VMethods.pod#pairs) vmethod to get a list of key/value pairs, which you can then sort into the order you want.

```
[% myList = { first => 'ZZZ', second => 'YYY', third => 'XXX' };
   FOREACH option IN myList.pairs.sort('value') -%]
<option value="[% option.key %]">[% option.value %]</option>
[% END -%]
```

Output:

```
<option value="third">XXX</option>
<option value="second">YYY</option>
<option value="first">ZZZ</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be easy enough to do by implementing a custom sort by value:

```
my @keys = sort { $hash{$a} cmp $hash{$b} } keys(%hash);
```

Unfortunately, looking over the [hash virtual methods](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_Hash_Virtual_Methods) available in TT, I don't think there's a way to do this purely in your template. You'll need to massage the data a little in code first, either through the `sort` above, or by inverting the hash:

```
my %inverted = reverse(%hash);
```

If you invert the hash, you can use the TT [pairs](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_pairs) method to get a sorted list of key/value pairs in one shot.

Comment: If there is a way to do it in template, don't. It is just not the right place, code that is perfectly readable becomes horrible in TT, because it is made to offer some simple ways of displaying the data prepared elsewhere, not to code in.

Comment: Agreed. The controller is a much better place to massage data.